# ksort on multidimensional array

Tags: php

I have a multidimensional array, and I need to sort that array by a specific key in that array.

I add to the array like this in a for loop

```
        $myArr[$i][0] = $row[1];

        $myArr[$i][1] = $row[2];

        $myArr[$i][2] = $row[3];
```

Now lets say that the value of $row[3] is DATE_ATOM.

How can i arrange the completed array by $myArr[$i][2]?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are probably looking for is [`array_multisort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php), specifically [this example usage](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php#example-4513) (Sorting database results).

For example (based on your code above):

```
$i = 0;
$myArr = $col1 = $col2 = $col3 = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $myArr[$i][0] = $col1[$i] = $row[1];
  $myArr[$i][1] = $col2[$i] = $row[2];
  $myArr[$i][2] = $col3[$i] = $row[3];
  $i++;
}

array_multisort($col3, SORT_ASC, $myArr);
var_dump($myArr);
```