# Sort 1st level keys and 2nd level keys of a 2d array

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I got a multidimensional array which may look like this:

```
$array[1][0] = "string";
$array[0][1] = "anotherstring";
$array[0][0] = "thirdstring";
$array[1][1] = "fourthstring";
```

I want to sort this array by keys so it looks like this:

```
$array[0][0] = "thirdstring";
$array[0][1] = "anotherstring";
$array[1][0] = "string";
$array[1][1] = "fourthstring";
```

At the moment I am using the following procedure:

```
ksort($array);
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        ksort($value);
        $array[$key] = $value;
}
```

This does work perfectly, but maybe there is a better (in-built) function to do this?

Comment: See [ksort on multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017418/ksort-on-multidimensional-array) but I think your 5 lines of code are sufficient.

Comment: array_multisort() is a built in function for multidimensional sorting.  In your code, I don't see the need for `$array[$key] = $value;`

Comment: @Devon There is a need for `$array[$key] = $value;`  
`foreach ($array as &$value) ksort($value);` would not need that

Comment: The array is already sorted. Or the example is misleading, being different from what you actually want to sort.

Comment: @Devon ksort($value) changes $value in place; $array[$key]=$value then puts the modified value back into the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can shorten your loop with:

```
ksort($array);
foreach($array as &$value) {
        ksort($value);
}
```

Or use `array_walk`:

```
ksort($array);
array_walk($array, 'ksort');
```